# What is a reliable way to implement an always on top overlay in a html page, which can be injected to any existing page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please note: I am not looking for the implementation (I will invest the effort myself), I am asking for the direction to start and/or idea which method to use.

I would like to implement an universal always on top movable (and optionally resizable) window/overlay on a html page. (Please note, this should not be a browser addin/extension)

This UI element should be injected to any (almost any?) existing page *without interfering* that existing UI and *without that existing page should know/care about* this injected part. (The injection will be done at server side)

What is the CSS/Html/Javascript method to implement this? 
(We can safely suppose/require modern browsers.)

Comment: Just make a jquery box that's draggable. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript:

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id','someuniquecontianerthingy');
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

or in jQuery

```
$(document.body).append('<div id="someuniquecontianerthingy"/>');
```

Then apply a [reset CSS](https://www.google.nl/webhp?#q=reset%20css) only on that div and it's children add default colours and background colours and border values to it too to cover your bases. Then have all your css classes prepended with your div#someuniquecontianerthingy

You can dynamically load css via

```
function loadCss(filename){
   var file=document.createElement("link");
   file.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   file.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
   file.setAttribute("href", filename);
   if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
       document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
 }
 loadCss("mystyle.css", "css")
```

which then applies the styles to your page.
Same function slightly modified you can use for script files to load up your javascript.

To make sure your css does not "affect current page layout" you need to set the position to either `fixed` of `absolute` whatever suits your needs.
This way the page will not "stretch to fit" or have a large empty gap.

your css would have to look like

```
div#someuniquecontianerthingy a { //somecode }
div#someuniquecontianerthingy a:hover { //somecode }
div#someuniquecontianerthingy  {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    color:#000;
    background:#FFF; 
}
```

and just make sure to define every property you can come up with the way you want it to look, borders, etc. Also make sure to choose unique id's classes for your styles so you have uniqueness.
Don't do your specific styles on id/class less things. That way you can beat most stylesheets by their specificity calculation.

In a CSS reset you'll have large blocks like

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
```

You will need to prepend every and each value with your unique selector

```
div#someuniquecontianerthingy html, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy body, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy div, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy span, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy applet, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy object, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy iframe,
div#someuniquecontianerthingy h1, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy h2, 
div#someuniquecontianerthingy h3, 
etc... {
}
```

Then it's a matter of filling your div with the content you want via your javascript script. If you use jQuery make sure you use a noConflict variant, so you will always have your own version of jQuery that's compatible with your code.

It's a lot of work, and still even if you try to guard against everything there might be issues where yoru code will break or the design will break, but if you take these steps it should be mostly stable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However if I _append_ a div to body that will affect to the existing page layout, which I definitely do not want. Missing I something?

Comment: No it does not...  Append means, to the end, like at the very end... just set it to `position:fixed` and you are good to go... I modified the answer. Sorry I assumed that would be self evident

Comment: In addition to that: You can not expect having a solution that does NOT use a browser extension if you want no DOM manipulation whatsoever. The key is to keep the new element out of your existing page layout (as Michael suggests by adding it to the very bottom, right before `</body>`) and style it accordingly.